# Unexpected NOTE: Namespace in Imports field not imported from: ‘R6’

Tags: r, cran

My (admittedly silly) package [twenty48](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/twenty48/index.html) is implemented using an R6 class. However, I get an unexpected R-CMD-check NOTE in [several flavors on CRAN](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/checks/check_results_twenty48.html):

> Namespace in Imports field not imported from: ‘R6’

I don't get this NOTE on my own Windows machine or on any of my GitHub actions instances.

I'm wondering if this occurs because I don't call R6 from within any of my functions. The only call to R6 is in a [separate file](https://github.com/rossellhayes/twenty48/blob/master/R/Twenty48_class.R) that constructs the R6 class.

Does R6 not need to be imported if it isn't called from within a function? Or should I change the structure of my package even though it functions correctly (e.g. place the constructor inside a function like `.onLoad()` or add an `importFrom()` to my `NAMESPACE`)?

Comment: I removed R6 label as it is not directly connected with R6 package

Answer (score 2):

This is a global problem on CRAN as additional check is added - Examples:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_cat2cat.html

https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_ggplot2.html

You have to add sth like that to .R file - Check if NAMESPACE file is updated:

```r
#' @import R6
NULL
```

to find out this NOTEs and check if everything is working correctly use rcmdcheck in rcmdcheck package.

```r
rcmdcheck::rcmdcheck()
```

Comment: Thank you, seems like this is the best option